# General MongoDB performance troubleshooting

Tags: mongodb, performance, meteor, reporting

TL;DR: 
Long running queries kill the whole app for other users. What is the strategy to circumvent that?

Hi, I am running MongoDB on AWS T2.small instance (2GB, 1 core) for a Meteor application with small traffic. It works fine unless people want to run a report that does about 30 aggregates to display various KPIs. While one user runs the report (it takes about a minute to finish), the app performance is terrible (almost zero), and the worst thing that can happen is that someone else starts the report for their own data at the same time. Then they it can take even 10 minutes to finish. The web server's load is almost none and does not cause the issue, but MongoDB server's CPU is running on 100% during such events (executing all individual aggregate calls with Meteor's unblock() gives no performance gain).

I know I could optimize individual queries or that I could pay more for a faster server, but that's not the point. How do I prevent the app lockout (users can't even login as the DB is busy as it doesn't have time to reply to user login requests)? I would like some mentoring.

Will replica sets help (e.g. hidden replica set member)? How would I target this one instance for reporting (from MeteorJS)? Is there a way to assign a low priority to such queries and do them in server's spare time only?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the aggregation queries are too much for the server to handle. If it's applicable to your use case, you might be able to create a pre-aggregated report.

The concept of pre-aggregated report is that when you insert new data into the collection, you also update an "aggregate document" in another collection. For example, if your aggregation needs a total value of some field, the `sum` field in the "aggregate document" will add the new document's value to the existing value.

Using a pre-aggregated report would remove the need to run the aggregation query. Instead, a single `db.aggregates.find()` query would be sufficient.

A drawback of this approach is that instead of a single insert operation, you would need an insert + an update.

Note that if the pre-aggregation approach is not suitable, then increasing your deployment's provisioning to a bigger machine would be the only realistic option.

Please see https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/use-cases/pre-aggregated-reports-mmapv1/ for some examples. Please note that although the technical details are for the MMAPv1 storage engine, the underlying concept will work equally well for the WiredTiger storage engine.

Comment: Hi  I am really interested in this issue. Can you explain why adding a replica set member won't help to solve it ?  Thanks

Comment: I originally wanted to implement some kind of pre-computation, but now I think it is not feasible. There is too many users running reports on any time periods wanting to display various indicators, which sometimes themselves refer to other records based on the selected period. Plus the amount of inserts/updates is huge, compared to reporting needs (some customers don't even use them).

While scaling the environment up is an option, it won't solve the problem in the long run. Customers can wait for reports, but they certainly want a responsive app for entering data.

Thank you though!

Comment: @Victor the main point of this specific case is that the deployment is too small to cope with the job it needs to do. Adding more replica set may help (e.g. with function-specific nodes such as a node dedicated to generating reports), but if the node is underpowered to begin with, you will just replace one problem with another. The workload sounds very "peaky" to me, which I think is the main reason why the node is t2.small. Also, a replica set is supposed to provide high availability, not to scale your workload. Instead, sharding is the preferred scaling method.